# How to apply discount amount in QuoteItem

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have code that saves order in Magento:

```
foreach ($poducts as $productData)
{
    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
    $quoteItem->setProduct($productData);
    $quoteItem->setQty(2);
    $quoteItem->setDiscountPercent($productData['discount_percent']);
    $quoteItem->setDiscountAmount($productData['discount_amount']);
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
    $quote->addItem($quoteItem);
}
```

I am wondering if there is way to apply discount why the setDiscountPercent and setDiscountAmount is not working. Is there other way to set discount on quoteItem?

Answer (score 0):

Discounts are bases on salesrules modules (Baskets and catalog promotion tab in magento admin panel)

Magento discounts are recalculated each times your quote is saved (and when you load the checkout page, when you add a product, etc)

You can't manually add some discount as it will be erased by magento standaard discounts mechanims.

Try to use catalog or baskets sales rules.

Comment: It is not completely true. I have been able to set discount on each item. I also can see discount on order. However, I can't get discounted amount in total/grandtotal

Comment: How to set discount without salerul/coupon http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/269154/. But I am still not been able to get total right on order (in Magento Admin)